# Can not start multiple containers in a Pod-Error syncing pod, skipping

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

My `kubectl version`

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"2", GitVersion:"v1.2.4", GitCommit:"3eed1e3be6848b877ff80a93da3785d9034d0a4f", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"2", GitVersion:"v1.2.4", GitCommit:"3eed1e3be6848b877ff80a93da3785d9034d0a4f", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

I followed [Creating Multi-Container Pods](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/pods/multi-container/)

After launching the pod, One container is UP but not other.

`kubectl get pods`

```
NAME                    READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
redis-django            1/2       CrashLoopBackOff   9          22m
```

Then I did `kubectl describe redis-django`. At the bottom I saw `Error syncing pod, skipping` error

```
  31m   <invalid>       150     {kubelet 172.25.30.21}  spec.containers{frontend}       Warning BackOff         Back-off restarting failed docker container
  25m   <invalid>       121     {kubelet 172.25.30.21}                                  Warning FailedSync      Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "frontend" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 5m0s restarting failed container=frontend pod=redis-django_default(9f35ffcd-391e-11e6-b160-0022195df673)"
```

How can I reslove this error? any help!

Thanks!

**OS: Ubuntu 14**

**UPDATE**

Previsoly I used below yaml file which was found at [Creating Multi-Container Pods](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/pods/multi-container/)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: redis-django
  labels:
    app: web
spec:
  containers:
    - name: key-value-store
      image: redis
      ports:
        - containerPort: 6379
    - name: frontend
      image: django
      ports:
        - containerPort: 8000
```

`frontend` container was not started. Then I changed the yaml file to two `redis` containers with different names and ports. But, the result is same(Getting Error syncing pod, skipping)

Later I have changed yaml file to, only one `django` container. This pod status `CrashLoopBackOff` and the `Error syncing pod, skipping`

**UPDATE-2**

I `tail -f /var/log/upstart/kublet.log`, which is giving same error. Kubelet is continously trying to start the container, but it is not!

```
I0623 12:15:13.943046     445 manager.go:2050] Back-off 5m0s restarting failed container=key-value-store pod=redis-django_default(94683d3c-392e-11e6-b160-0022195df673)
E0623 12:15:13.943100     445 pod_workers.go:138] Error syncing pod 94683d3c-392e-11e6-b160-0022195df673, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "key-value-store" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 5m0s restarting failed container=key-value-store pod=redis-django_default(94683d3c-392e-11e6-b160-0022195df673)"
```

**UPDATE-3**

```
root@vm1:~/kubernetes/cluster/ubuntu/binaries# kubectl describe pod redis-django
Name:           redis-django
Namespace:      default
Node:           192.168.1.10/192.168.1.10
Start Time:     Thu, 23 Jun 2016 22:58:03 -0700
Labels:         app=web
Status:         Running
IP:             172.16.20.2
Controllers:    <none>
Containers:
  key-value-store:
    Container ID:       docker://8dbdd6826c354243964f0306427082223d3da49bf2aaf30e15961ea00362fe42
    Image:              redis
    Image ID:           docker://sha256:4465e4bcad80b5b43cef0bace96a8ef0a55c0050be439c1fb0ecd64bc0b8cce4
    Port:               6379/TCP
    QoS Tier:
      cpu:              BestEffort
      memory:           BestEffort
    State:              Running
      Started:          Thu, 23 Jun 2016 22:58:10 -0700
    Ready:              True
    Restart Count:      0
    Environment Variables:
  frontend:
    Container ID:       docker://9c89602739abe7331b3beb3a79e92a7cc42e2a7e40e11618413c8bcfd0afbc16
    Image:              django
    Image ID:           docker://sha256:0cb63b45e2b9a8de5763fc9c98b79c38b6217df718238251a21c8c4176fb3d68
    Port:               8000/TCP
    QoS Tier:
      cpu:              BestEffort
      memory:           BestEffort
    State:              Terminated
      Reason:           Completed
      Exit Code:        0
      Started:          Thu, 23 Jun 2016 22:58:41 -0700
      Finished:         Thu, 23 Jun 2016 22:58:41 -0700
    Last State:         Terminated
      Reason:           Completed
      Exit Code:        0
      Started:          Thu, 23 Jun 2016 22:58:22 -0700
      Finished:         Thu, 23 Jun 2016 22:58:22 -0700
    Ready:              False
    Restart Count:      2
    Environment Variables:
Conditions:
  Type          Status
  Ready         False 
Volumes:
  default-token-0oq7p:
    Type:       Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName: default-token-0oq7p
Events:
  FirstSeen     LastSeen        Count   From                    SubobjectPath                           Type            Reason           Message
  ---------     --------        -----   ----                    -------------                           --------        ------           -------
  49s           49s             1       {default-scheduler }                                            Normal          Scheduled        Successfully assigned redis-django to 192.168.1.10
  48s           48s             1       {kubelet 192.168.1.10}  spec.containers{key-value-store}        Normal          Pulling          pulling image "redis"
  43s           43s             1       {kubelet 192.168.1.10}  spec.containers{key-value-store}        Normal          Pulled           Successfully pulled image "redis"
  43s           43s             1       {kubelet 192.168.1.10}  spec.containers{key-value-store}        Normal          Created          Created container with docker id 8dbdd6826c35
  42s           42s             1       {kubelet 192.168.1.10}  spec.containers{key-value-store}        Normal          Started          Started container with docker id 8dbdd6826c35
  37s           37s             1       {kubelet 192.168.1.10}  spec.containers{frontend}               Normal          Started          Started container with docker id 3872ceae75d4
  37s           37s             1       {kubelet 192.168.1.10}  spec.containers{frontend}               Normal          Created          Created container with docker id 3872ceae75d4
  30s           30s             1       {kubelet 192.168.1.10}  spec.containers{frontend}               Normal          Created          Created container with docker id d97b99b6780c
  30s           30s             1       {kubelet 192.168.1.10}  spec.containers{frontend}               Normal          Started          Started container with docker id d97b99b6780c
  29s           29s             1       {kubelet 192.168.1.10}                                          Warning         FailedSync       Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "frontend" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 10s restarting failed container=frontend pod=redis-django_default(9d0a966a-39d0-11e6-9027-000c293d51ab)"

  42s   16s     3       {kubelet 192.168.1.10}  spec.containers{frontend}       Normal  Pulling         pulling image "django"
  11s   11s     1       {kubelet 192.168.1.10}  spec.containers{frontend}       Normal  Started         Started container with docker id 9c89602739ab
  38s   11s     3       {kubelet 192.168.1.10}  spec.containers{frontend}       Normal  Pulled          Successfully pulled image "django"
  11s   11s     1       {kubelet 192.168.1.10}  spec.containers{frontend}       Normal  Created         Created container with docker id 9c89602739ab
  29s   10s     2       {kubelet 192.168.1.10}  spec.containers{frontend}       Warning BackOff         Back-off restarting failed docker container
  10s   10s     1       {kubelet 192.168.1.10}                                  Warning FailedSync      Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "frontend" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 20s restarting failed container=frontend pod=redis-django_default(9d0a966a-39d0-11e6-9027-000c293d51ab)"
```

For container `frontend`: Not showing any logs messages

```
root@vm1:~/kubernetes/cluster/ubuntu/binaries# kubectl logs redis-django -p -c frontend
root@vm1:~/kubernetes/cluster/ubuntu/binaries# kubectl logs redis-django -p -c key-value-store
Error from server: previous terminated container "key-value-store" in pod "redis-django" not found
root@vm1:~/kubernetes/cluster/ubuntu/binaries# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
8dbdd6826c35        redis                                "docker-entrypoint.sh"   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes                            k8s_key-value-store.f572c2d_redis-django_default_9d0a966a-39d0-11e6-9027-000c293d51ab_11101aea
8995bbf9f4f4        gcr.io/google_containers/pause:2.0   "/pause"                 2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes                            k8s_POD.48e5231f_redis-django_default_9d0a966a-39d0-11e6-9027-000c293d51ab_c00025b0
root@vm1:~/kubernetes/cluster/ubuntu/binaries#
```

Comment: Does kubelet.log provide any clue? It should be under /var/log/ of the node machine.

Comment: Just checked the log. There also, it is showing same error.(You can see in my question `UPDATE-2`)

Comment: I have checked in my Laptop also (Ubuntu- Single Node Kubernetes). Getting same errors in `logs` and `kubectl describe pod <POD>` :-(

Comment: The log is saying it's in the crash loop. I think this message has been repeated many times and in the first one it should tell the reason. Could you paste the entire `kubectl describe` output?

Comment: As @caesarxuchao mentioned, the output of `kubectl describe <pod_name>` should include the termination reason for the last container. In addition to that, you can check the logs of the last terminated container with `kubectl logs <pod_name> -p -c <contianer_name> `

Comment: ok, added some more log info, any help?(`UPDATE-3`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah...your django container exited voluntarily without any error message, right after it was started, and that's *expected*.

The django image comes with a default command of `python3`. Without overriding the command/args in the pod yaml file, the container will exit immediately.

The [doc](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/pods/multi-container/) you followed was simply trying to show how to create multiple containers in a pod, but the example is not realistic and doesn't set up a working application. Feel free to file a github issue against https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes.github.io